# FancyBox Image click not working after reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

First time when i click on image it enlarge and no issue. But when i try to reload the page without clear the cache having issue on loading image upon click action. If i reload with clear cache again no issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title: { type: 'outside' },
                buttons: {},
                type: 'iframe',
                overlay:
                {
                    showEarly: false
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="@imgSrc1">
    <img src="@imgSrc1" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried placing your JS code after HTML content?

Comment: @Janis Yes, already tried to place JS code after HTML still same issue. If i try to do Hard reload from chrome browser and try click on image it enlarge.